# Pivot a dataframe using polars.pivot() (like pivot_longer in R)

Tags: python, pivot, python-polars

Coming from R I am remaking some exercises that helped me a lot. So Trying to recreate this R code:

```
wide_data <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rafalab/dslabs/master/inst/extdata/life-expectancy-and-fertility-two-countries-example.csv')

new_tidy_data <- pivot_longer(wide_data, `1960`:`2015`, names_to = "year", values_to = "fertility")
```

The data looks like this (I don't know how to paste the output)
but has 113 columns: First is country, and then 1960_fertility 1960_life_expectancy 1961_fertility 1961_life_expectancy ..... 2015_fertility 2015_life_expectancy

and 2 rows germany, south Korea

expected result:

```
head(new_tidy_data)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 3
#>   country year  fertility
#>   <chr>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 Germany 1960       2.41
#> 2 Germany 1961       2.44
#> 3 Germany 1962       2.47
#> 4 Germany 1963       2.49
#> 5 Germany 1964       2.49
#> # ℹ 1 more row
```

So far my code looks like this:

```
import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs

df = pl.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rafalab/dslabs/master/inst/extdata/life-expectancy-and-fertility-two-countries-example.csv')
df.pivot()
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In polars you've got [`pivot`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pivot.html#polars.DataFrame.pivot) which makes things wider and then [`melt`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html#polars.DataFrame.melt) (think of icicles) to make them longer.

Melt won't split up the single columns with a delimitator into two columns for you, you've got to do that yourself.

That looks like this...

```
(
    df
    .melt('country', value_name='fertility')
    .with_columns(
        pl.col('variable').str.splitn('_',2).struct.rename_fields(['year','var'])
    )
    .unnest('variable')
    .filter(pl.col('var')=='fertility')
    .drop('var')
    .sort('country')
)
```

The way polars expressions work is that for every input there is just one output but there's a type called a [struct](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/structs/#__tabbed_1_1) which can be nested with as many columns as is needed. In that way we [`splitn`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.splitn.html#polars.Expr.str.splitn) the variable column into the year part and the var part. We can convert that struct into two regular columns with [`unnest`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest) which is dispatched at the df level rather than as an expression.

On second though, since you want to filter for only fertility anyway, you can pre-filter and rename the columns before you melt like this:

```
(
    df
    .select(
        pl.col("^(country|.+fertility)$")
        .name.map(lambda x: x.replace("_fertility", "")))
    .melt('country', variable_name='year', value_name='fertility')
    .sort('country')
)
shape: (112, 3)
┌─────────────┬──────┬───────────┐
│ country     ┆ year ┆ fertility │
│ ---         ┆ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str         ┆ str  ┆ f64       │
╞═════════════╪══════╪═══════════╡
│ Germany     ┆ 1960 ┆ 2.41      │
│ Germany     ┆ 1961 ┆ 2.44      │
│ Germany     ┆ 1962 ┆ 2.47      │
│ Germany     ┆ 1963 ┆ 2.49      │
│ Germany     ┆ 1964 ┆ 2.49      │
│ …           ┆ …    ┆ …         │
│ South Korea ┆ 2011 ┆ 1.29      │
│ South Korea ┆ 2012 ┆ 1.3       │
│ South Korea ┆ 2013 ┆ 1.32      │
│ South Korea ┆ 2014 ┆ 1.34      │
│ South Korea ┆ 2015 ┆ 1.36      │
└─────────────┴──────┴───────────┘
```

#### Lastly

If you wanted a column for fertility and life_expectancy, you'd need to combine the first approach with a pivot at the end like this:

```
(
    df
    .melt('country')
    .with_columns(
        pl.col('variable').str.splitn('_',2).struct.rename_fields(['year','var'])
    )
    .unnest('variable')
    .pivot(
        values='value', index=['country','year'], 
        columns='var', aggregate_function='first')
    .sort('country')
shape: (112, 4)
┌─────────────┬──────┬───────────┬─────────────────┐
│ country     ┆ year ┆ fertility ┆ life_expectancy │
│ ---         ┆ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---             │
│ str         ┆ str  ┆ f64       ┆ f64             │
╞═════════════╪══════╪═══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ Germany     ┆ 1960 ┆ 2.41      ┆ 69.26           │
│ Germany     ┆ 1961 ┆ 2.44      ┆ 69.85           │
│ Germany     ┆ 1962 ┆ 2.47      ┆ 70.01           │
│ Germany     ┆ 1963 ┆ 2.49      ┆ 70.1            │
│ Germany     ┆ 1964 ┆ 2.49      ┆ 70.66           │
│ …           ┆ …    ┆ …         ┆ …               │
│ South Korea ┆ 2011 ┆ 1.29      ┆ 80.6            │
│ South Korea ┆ 2012 ┆ 1.3       ┆ 80.7            │
│ South Korea ┆ 2013 ┆ 1.32      ┆ 80.9            │
│ South Korea ┆ 2014 ┆ 1.34      ┆ 80.9            │
│ South Korea ┆ 2015 ┆ 1.36      ┆ 81.0            │
└─────────────┴──────┴───────────┴─────────────────┘
)
```

Comment: Holy moly so much stuff to think about. So in the last code you had to combine a melt to make the colum var and then pivot that. I see why my thought process was incorrect. Huge thanks, I'll keep practicing